# Makes sense? Expert UX Designer making Visual Design choices

Tags: usability, design

There have been design choices made by someone with a PhD degree in UX that I've questioned. I've noticed poor choice of iconography, or placement of elements on first sight.

My reasoning usually tends to be related to obsession with UI elements' order, cleanliness, familiarity, and consistency. Any stray visual elements that do not have obvious relations cause me anxiety.

Does it make sense to have UX designers make visual design choices? Rules of color, composition, lighting do come into play to some extent in any visual design–including UI design.

Comment: Do you guys have a designated visual designer? Who's the lead? Is he the lead? What are reviews like where you work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the only possible correct answer is "it depends" and it won't help anyone

Comment: I guess you will need to consider the reasons behind the design choices made by the expert UX designer and see if these are supported by some research or testing that in fact improves the usability by sacrificing some of the visual aesthetics of the user interface. But if it is based on personal opinions then I would question the decisions because there should be a basis for the design decision, especially coming from an expert in the field.

Comment: @Devin IMO, it will have use for someone (especially someone who has a management position, etc.). I was baffled by some design choices that were made. For example, s/he reasoned that circular UI elements afford clickability. I never even thought of clicking on the circular element presented in one of screens. I accidentally figured it out.

Comment: I fully understand and even sympathize with what you say, I have seen this before. However, many Expert UX designers are also very capable UI designers. I bet at least 30% of the people in this board comes from teh design field. So the answer is.... it depends. The case you mention is one extreme, and there's the exact opposite extreme: design superstars that moved to UX. And then everything in between. Bottom line is: there's no correct answer other than "it depends"

Answer (score 3):

I came to UX Design from the visual side of Interaction Design. Others come to it from psychology, business, marketing, development, and from other directions. If your UX Designer came from a non-visual design background, you probably don't want to give them a visual-design role on the project. Hire actual visual designers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no black and white answer about who should decide what in the design process, but *typically*, the UX-designer should be **analyzing, testing, and adjusting**  to optimize the user experience (flow, function, information), **not *necessarily* making graphic design choices.** While **many UX professionals are quite gifted UI-designers**, it doesn´t follow that **all** UX professionals are gifted visual designers.

Since user experience design definitely encompasses an end users´s emotions and attitudes while they use something — including the impact of the visual design  — **you should not exclude your UX professional from the design decision process.**   If you are on a small team and have a better eye, and the roles/responsibilities are unclear, appeal to the UX professionals analytical nature and/or find a way to argue for visual design changes with testing (A/B testing for example).

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what their background entails, prototyping vs finished product etc.

Not all UX designers have visual design experience. Make an argument for why something should be different and present it well during review, or vice-versa ask for the process behind why they've done something.